# Pan Responder simply not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am on React Native .61.

I am trying to use a library that uses Pan Responder, and it just is not working.

This is my code:

```
<Swiper
                    ref={this.swiper}
                    onSwiped={(cardIndex) => this.onSwiped('general', cardIndex)}
                    onSwipedLeft={(cardIndex) => this.onSwiped('left', cardIndex)}
                    onSwipedRight={(cardIndex) => this.onSwiped('right', cardIndex)}
                    cards={this.state.offers}
                    cardIndex={this.state.cardIndex}
                    cardVerticalMargin={20}
                    infinite={true}
                    disableTopSwipe={true}
                    disableBottomSwipe={true}
                    renderCard={this.renderCard}
                    onSwipedAll={this.onSwipedAllCards}
                    stackSize={3}
                    stackSeparation={15}
                    overlayLabels={{
                        left: {
                            title: 'NOPE',
                            style: {
                                label: {
                                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                                    borderColor: 'black',
                                    color: 'white',
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                },
                                wrapper: {
                                    flexDirection: 'column',
                                    alignItems: 'flex-end',
                                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                                    marginTop: 30,
                                    marginLeft: -30
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        right: {
                            title: 'LIKE',
                            style: {
                                label: {
                                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                                    borderColor: 'black',
                                    color: 'white',
                                    borderWidth: 1
                                },
                                wrapper: {
                                    flexDirection: 'column',
                                    alignItems: 'flex-start',
                                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                                    marginTop: 30,
                                    marginLeft: 30
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }}
                    animateOverlayLabelsOpacity
                    animateCardOpacity
                    swipeBackCard
                >

                </Swiper>

                <Buttons onSwiped={this.onSwiped} {...this.props} swiper={this.swiper} />
```

This is pan responder usage inside the module:

```
initializePanResponder = () => {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,

      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const isVerticalSwipe = Math.sqrt(
          Math.pow(gestureState.dx, 2) < Math.pow(gestureState.dy, 2)
        )
        if (!this.props.verticalSwipe && isVerticalSwipe) {
          return false
        }
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(gestureState.dx, 2) + Math.pow(gestureState.dy, 2)) > 10
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: this.onPanResponderGrant,
      onPanResponderMove: this.onPanResponderMove,
      onPanResponderRelease: this.onPanResponderRelease,
      onPanResponderTerminate: this.onPanResponderRelease
    })
  }



onPanResponderGrant = (event, gestureState) => {
    this.props.dragStart && this.props.dragStart()
    if (!this.state.panResponderLocked) {
      this.state.pan.setOffset({
        x: this._animatedValueX,
        y: this._animatedValueY
      })
    }

    this.state.pan.setValue({
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    })
  }



onPanResponderMove = (event, gestureState) => {
    this.props.onSwiping(this._animatedValueX, this._animatedValueY)

    let { overlayOpacityHorizontalThreshold, overlayOpacityVerticalThreshold } = this.props
    if (!overlayOpacityHorizontalThreshold) {
      overlayOpacityHorizontalThreshold = this.props.horizontalThreshold
    }
    if (!overlayOpacityVerticalThreshold) {
      overlayOpacityVerticalThreshold = this.props.verticalThreshold
    }

    let isSwipingLeft,
      isSwipingRight,
      isSwipingTop,
      isSwipingBottom

    if (Math.abs(this._animatedValueX) > Math.abs(this._animatedValueY) && Math.abs(this._animatedValueX) > overlayOpacityHorizontalThreshold) {
      if (this._animatedValueX > 0) isSwipingRight = true
      else isSwipingLeft = true
    } else if (Math.abs(this._animatedValueY) > Math.abs(this._animatedValueX) && Math.abs(this._animatedValueY) > overlayOpacityVerticalThreshold) {
      if (this._animatedValueY > 0) isSwipingBottom = true
      else isSwipingTop = true
    }

    if (isSwipingRight) {
      this.setState({ labelType: LABEL_TYPES.RIGHT })
    } else if (isSwipingLeft) {
      this.setState({ labelType: LABEL_TYPES.LEFT })
    } else if (isSwipingTop) {
      this.setState({ labelType: LABEL_TYPES.TOP })
    } else if (isSwipingBottom) {
      this.setState({ labelType: LABEL_TYPES.BOTTOM })
    } else {
      this.setState({ labelType: LABEL_TYPES.NONE })
    }

    const { onTapCardDeadZone } = this.props
    if (
      this._animatedValueX < -onTapCardDeadZone ||
      this._animatedValueX > onTapCardDeadZone ||
      this._animatedValueY < -onTapCardDeadZone ||
      this._animatedValueY > onTapCardDeadZone
    ) {
      this.setState({
        slideGesture: true
      })
    }

    return Animated.event([null, this.createAnimatedEvent()])(
      event,
      gestureState
    )
  }

  onPanResponderRelease = (e, gestureState) => {
    this.props.dragEnd && this.props.dragEnd()
    if (this.state.panResponderLocked) {
      this.state.pan.setValue({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      })
      this.state.pan.setOffset({
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      })

      return
    }

    const { horizontalThreshold, verticalThreshold } = this.props

    const animatedValueX = Math.abs(this._animatedValueX)
    const animatedValueY = Math.abs(this._animatedValueY)

    const isSwiping =
      animatedValueX > horizontalThreshold || animatedValueY > verticalThreshold

    if (isSwiping && this.validPanResponderRelease()) {
      const onSwipeDirectionCallback = this.getOnSwipeDirectionCallback(
        this._animatedValueX,
        this._animatedValueY
      )

      this.swipeCard(onSwipeDirectionCallback)
    } else {
      this.resetTopCard()
    }

    if (!this.state.slideGesture) {
      this.props.onTapCard(this.state.firstCardIndex)
    }

    this.setState({
      labelType: LABEL_TYPES.NONE,
      slideGesture: false
    })
  }
```

I've been trying to figure this out all day - for some reason the library just does not work on Android.

I've considered switching it out for another one or writing my own, but I already have my iOS code working and I'm loathe to totally replace it, especially when my guess is that it is a fairly simple Pan Responder issue.

The library in question is this one:

https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper

Answer (score 3):

I needed to apply `<View style={{flex: 1}}>` to ALL parent views.

If any view was not set to `flex: 1`, this plugin would not work.